# Mocha not recognized after windows 10 update

Tags: windows, npm, mocha.js

I'm no longer able to run mocha after installing the recent Windows 10 update. Rolling the update back is not an option. This is the error I'm getting:

```
mocha : The term 'mocha' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mocha .\mascusToCdhTransformationServiceTest.js
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mocha:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried reinstalling my npm application. I noticed that it didn't recognize my python installation. I fixed that by running

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

I've also tried several variations of

```
npm install mocha
npm install mocha -g
npm uninstall
npm install
```

All seemingly succeed but I still get the error that Windows doesn't recognize mocha. Is there something I can do to get Windows to run mocha again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add ~\AppData\Roaming\npm to my environment path variable. I'm not sure why it was removed, but adding it back resolved the issue.